# Getting grid coordinates of cells bordering a square region

Tags: unity

I have a board that is 4x4 ( the blue cells) with the origin (0 , 0) being in the bottom left for example, how can I get the coords which are adjacent to the board (the red cells) to store them in an array?

[image: Filled square of blue cells surrounded by a square of red cells]

Comment: Is this grid generated at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For any given square (or rectangle) with the upper left hand corner at (Px, Py) with a width of m and a height of n the border will be (Px-1 <= x <= Px+m+1, {Py-1, Py+n+1}) and ({Px-1, Px+m+1}, Py-1 <= y <= Py+n+1).

Comment: Note that the question says the origin is at the bottom-left. So y is likely increasing upward (as is the Unity convention), not downward as shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the positions between (-1;-1) and (4;4), and if the position is less, than 0 or larger, than 3 on any axis, then add that to a list.

There are definitely more performant options, but unless you're working with boards thousands of cells wide, you won't run into problems.

Comment: What if the board wasnt at 0,0 and maybe like 14,0?

Comment: @user Then you loop through those

Comment: Given a rectangle of width m and a height of n the number of squares on the perimeter is 2n + 2m - 2. Iterating over the rectangle increases the overhead by n*m + c. Instead see [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166819/49858) response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to just include those red cells in array, so it won't be a problem to store them.

If you want to set bottom left cell exactly as (0, 0), you can something like this:

```
private Vector2Int greenCellsStartPoint;

public Vector2Int GetGreenCellOnGrid(Vector2Int position) // position from the bottom left cell
{
    return greenCellsStartPoint + position;
}
```

In this case you can store as many red cells as you want in array, this is doesn't really a problem, position in Unity is relative.